# Cannot able to edit the response in the twitter field after getting response from the api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, artificial-intelligence, browser-extension

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', async function(event) {
  var target = event.target;

  //twitter

  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'div' && target.getAttribute('role') === 'textbox') {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      var userInput = target.innerText;

      if (userInput.startsWith('/ai') && userInput.indexOf('/ai') === userInput.lastIndexOf('/ai')) {
        console.log('User input:', userInput);
        if (userInput) {
          const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}`, {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${key}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              model: "text-davinci-003",
              prompt: userInput,
              max_tokens: 1000
            })
          });
          const data = await response.json();
          console.log(`OpenAI API response →`, data);
  
          const output = data.choices[0].text;
          target.innerText = output;
        }
        else {
          console.error("Error");
        }
      }
    }
  }});
```

so we i get response for the api to perfectely comes in the twitter input box but after that i am not able to edit of modify the api response in the input field this browser extension is working fine in the on other  sites so can you guys help me with this ?

i want to modify the twitter input field after the api response comes in the twitter input field